# Обновление информации в окне PyQt4

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, pyqt4, pyside

При написании собственной программы возникли некоторые трудности с обновлением информации в окне. Так, перерыв множество сайтов я наткнулся на решение проблемы, но оно не помогло. Суть в том, что нужно после добавления кнопки обновить информацию в окне(чтобы кнопку без перезапуска видно было), но с методом, подсказанным мне Google'ом, имеющихся кнопок стает вдвое больше
[image: До]
[image: После]

Сам код:

```
##Layout, где располагаются кнопки
self.grid_layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
self.grid_layout.setSpacing(10) 
...
##Удаление
for button in self.grid_buttons:  ##self.grid_buttons - список, содержащий все кнопки в self.grid_layout
    self.grid_layout.removeWidget(button)
    button.setParent(None)
    del button
self.notes_grid_loading()##функция прогрузки кнопок и их добавление в Layout
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось сделать код минимального размера, добавив цикл while:

```
while len(self.grid_buttons) > 0:
   for button in self.grid_buttons:  ##self.grid_buttons - список, содержащий все кнопки в self.grid_layout
      self.grid_layout.removeWidget(button)
      button.setParent(None)
      del button
   self.notes_grid_loading()##функция прогрузки кнопок и их добавление в Layout
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QGridLayout

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self._layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self._layout)

        self.get_bt()
        self.get_bt()

    def get_bt(self):
        b_add = QPushButton(self, text='добавить кнопку')
        b_add.clicked.connect(self.get_bt)

        b_remove = QPushButton(self, text='удалить кнопку')
        b_remove.clicked.connect(lambda: b_add.deleteLater() or b_remove.deleteLater())

        self._layout.addWidget(b_add)
        self._layout.addWidget(b_remove)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    qa = QApplication([])
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    qa.exec_()
```